# How can I simply use one perl script in any folder?

Tags: perl, path, directory

I have just added this script to PATH variable, but it does not work.

I need to use it in any directory as:

```
perl script.pl SOME ARGUMENTS
```

I have windows 7 Ultimate.

Thank you for advices!

Answer (score 2):

While the system is using `PATH` to find the program to run, the system is executing `perl`, not `script.pl`.

Either tell `perl` to search `PATH` for the script,

```
perl -S script.pl SOME ARGUMENTS
```

Or launch the script directly.

```
script.pl SOME ARGUMENTS
```

Windows will use file associations to determine how to launch the file in the latter case.